# Code unreachable when adding Selenium ChromeOptions

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler, chrome-options

For some reason my Python code displays as unreachable after adding a series of WebDriver options. Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed?
[image]

Code itself is below:

```
class DriverOptions(object):

  def __init__(self):

    self.options = Options()
    self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    self.options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
    self.options.add_argument('--single-process')
    self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    self.options.add_argument("--incognito")
    self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    self.options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    self.options.add_argument("disable-infobars")

    self.helperSpoofer = Spoofer()

    self.options.add_argument('user-agent={}'.format(self.helperSpoofer.userAgent))
    self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % self.helperSpoofer.ip)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in Selenium 4.0. Just try updating your pip and simply uninstalling the selenium and reinstalling it. It solved a problem for me.

```
pip install selenium --upgrade
```

Comment: This worked for me, I was getting the same error whenever using `Webdriver.Chrome`

Comment: Worked for me, updating from `3.141.0` to `4.7.2`. Let me add this bug is a wasted-all-afternoon level bug.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are using too many arguments and you can remove some of the arguments which are no more relevant:

- Remove the *`--no-sandbox`* argument and execute as ***non-root*** user.
- Either use *`--start-maximized`* or *`--start-fullscreen`*, avoid using both.
- If you aren't using *`--no-sandbox`* you can also remove *`--disable-dev-shm-usage'`*
- Remove the *`--incognito`* argument as it is no more effective.
- Remove the *`--disable-infobars`* argument as it is no more effective.
- Add the argument *`'--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled'`* only once.
- The argument [***`--single-process`***](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#single-process) looks to me an ***overkill*** as it *runs the renderer and plugins in the same process as the browser* and you may like to drop it.

A simpler yet effective code block can be:

```
class DriverOptions(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.options = Options()
        self.options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
        self.options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        self.options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
        self.helperSpoofer = Spoofer()
        self.options.add_argument('user-agent={}'.format(self.helperSpoofer.userAgent))
        self.options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % self.helperSpoofer.ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is in selenium v4.1.3-4.1.4.

Update the Selenium library.